# A good explanation for roles/profiles/permission sets and sharing

Tags: profile, sharing, permission-sets, roles

I know what each of these things are, but I have a hard time articulating it to non salesforce people.  I suspect there is a tool out there that unpacks it in a visual way and makes it all more memorable and intuitive.  Does anyone have a good visual representation of these salesforce terms?

Comment: This slideshare has a good amount of visual slides around this. Maybe you will find one that helps it stick: https://www.slideshare.net/Salesforce/get-it-right-the-first-time-user-administration

Comment: the 'who sees what' video series is generally well regarded.  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6747B4DAE356E17C

Comment: At a basic level, you can compare user permissions (profiles/permission sets) to driver's licenses, and sharing settings (roles/sharing rules) to local laws that restrict licensed users. Almost everyone that's driven a car understands this analogy. You can then carry on with all sorts of specific examples. You can't drive a semi without a commercial license, and you can't drive a semi in areas where it's restricted. You'll often find there's all sorts of real-life analogies you can draw from; the actual ideas are not that foreign to most people.

Comment: The easiest way I explain Profiles and Sharings to my junior developers is: _Profiles dictates what users can do with object_ and _Sharings is what records user can see_. 
I would add that Permission sets are same as Profiles and roles are same as Sharings but both can be added separately. Profiles and Sharings are the basic concept to understand.

Answer (score 6):

You can check this link
http://hellosnl.blogspot.com/2017/08/salesforce-security-concepts.html

Also check this image
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[This video](https://play.vidyard.com/kXk6BaNlWJP27UyFO8vNUg) from the 'Who Sees What' series does a good job of explaining the differences at a high-level.

I'd recommend doing the [Data Security](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/force_com_admin_intermediate/modules/data_security) trailhead for even more clarification.